# Does Forge translates IfcGrid elements from an IFC file

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

BIM (IFC) models often contain custom grids which are vital to large buildings. IFC represents the grids with `IfcGrid`. The viewer doesn't contain information regarding `IfcGrid` elements.

1. Does the model derivative API translate the grid information (`IfcGrid`)?
2. Does the viewer support showing these elements?

Answer (score 0):

The Model Derivative service typically tries to extract sufficient amount of detail for visualization and analysis, while also keeping the output size in bounds to maintain good loading times and runtime performance.

If you do not see the `IfcGrid` data in the properties or the scene hierarchy, then this is most likely one of the components that is excluded from the extraction. In that case you can use the Design Automation service, and extract any type of information you need from the IFC file using a custom Revit plugin.